# Custom Fontello icons display incorrectly on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, mobile, fontello

I have exported a set of icons from Sketch as SVGs and processed them through Fontello to use on my website. Everything is fine for desktop (including mobile views) but the inner paths seem to "disappear" on mobile devices specifically.

I've tested this on iOS and Android, with the default Safari browser, Android web browser, and google chrome for mobile and had the same result.

In Sketch, I am using a Combined Shape with Union 
I have attempted this with Adobe Illustrator as well, but I had the same result.

How it shows on Desktop:
[icons on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iOxn.jpg)

How it shows on mobile devices
[icons on mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iOxn.jpg)

Here is an example of the SVG my Sketch has exported.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="113px" height="113px" viewBox="0 0 113 113" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 3.6 (26304) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<title>Combined Shape</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g id="Introduction" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Facebook" transform="translate(-1.000000, -1.000000)" fill="#000000">
        <path d="M114,57.5 C114,26.2959116 88.7040884,1 57.5,1 C26.2959116,1 1,26.2959116 1,57.5 C1,88.7040884 26.2959116,114 57.5,114 C88.7040884,114 114,88.7040884 114,57.5 L114,57.5 L114,57.5 L114,57.5 L114,57.5 L114,57.5 Z M49.9465,88.7759701 L61.4605,88.7759701 L61.4605,59.8388273 L71.0245,59.8388273 L72.5035,48.5534939 L61.4605,48.5534939 L61.4605,41.3001606 C61.4605,39.5233987 61.8655,38.1550177 62.6065,37.1980654 C63.3475,36.3081606 64.7605,35.8296844 66.9145,35.8296844 L72.7735,35.8296844 L72.7735,25.7725415 C70.7545,25.4312082 67.9255,25.2940654 64.2235,25.2940654 C59.9125,25.2940654 56.4115,26.5923511 53.8525,29.1950177 C51.2275,31.7915892 49.9465,35.4853035 49.9465,40.2060654 L49.9465,48.5534939 L40.3855,48.5534939 L40.3855,59.8388273 L49.9465,59.8388273 L49.9465,88.7759701 L49.9465,88.7759701 L49.9465,88.7759701 L49.9465,88.7759701 L49.9465,88.7759701 Z" id="Combined-Shape"></path>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

FYI Fontello doesn't support fill-rule or fill. Still trying to figure out how to get around this w/ my icon but it will cause the behavior you are describing.